# What value pass in argument of transfer function of ERC223 Token

Tags: solidity, erc-223

I am implementing a ERC223 token.I successfully deployed ERC223 token on local block-chain network block-chain.

**transfer** function **solidity**  **code** is:-

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) {
        // Standard function transfer similar to ERC20 transfer with no _data .
        // Added due to backwards compatibility reasons .
        uint codeLength;

    assembly {
        // Retrieve the size of the code on target address, this needs assembly .
        codeLength := extcodesize(_to)
    }

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    if(codeLength>0) {
        ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
    }
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
}


function transfer(address _to, uint _value) {
    uint codeLength;
    bytes memory empty;

    assembly {
        // Retrieve the size of the code on target address, this needs assembly .
        codeLength := extcodesize(_to)
    }

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    if(codeLength>0) {
        ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, empty);
    }
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, empty);
}
```

One thing I can not understand.What value I passed in transfer function arguments. when I checked my ERC223 token working correctly or not??

1.What should be **address _to** value in transfer function?

2.What should be **uint _value** in transfer function?

3.What should be **bytes data** in transfer function?

4.what params should be given in place of _data?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.What should be address _to value in transfer function?
```

Sender will send tokens `to` whom/what? Type: address.

```
2.What should be uint _value in transfer function?
```

Sender will how many tokens to receiver? Type: uint.

```
3.What should be bytes data in transfer function?
```

This is not an argument in the transfer function. Where do you see that?

```
4.what params should be given in place of _data?
```

If the receiver is a contract it may have a tokenFallback function to run when these tokens are received. `_data` will send arbitrary information to this function, the meaning of which will be on a case-by-case basis. This is your opportunity to implement application-specific logic without breaking the standard.

This argument is optional. It's passed through with this line:

`receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);`

Note that are two implementations of `transfer`. Each transaction will run one or the other depending on the number of arguments passed. That is, with or without the optional `bytes _data`.

Hope it helps.